# React-Native update UI when value on element in array changes, without using ForceUpdate

Tags: user-interface, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

Imagine this: I have a `FlatList` presenting a list of message threads. Each cell has a label showing number of new messages in that thread. Each cell also shows a truncated string of the latest message in that thread. Other things are presented too. The list of threads is kept in `redux` and is set as the data prop for my `FlatList`. The class instances for the threads do not know of the FlatList  and cannot force reload on it when something changes, eg a new message comes in (intentional design). The issue now is that the `FlatList` does not update when such an event occurs. It only updates when a new thread array is set (new instance).

How can I get the `FlatList` to update when any of the values in the threads changes?

A timed recurring reload is not preferred. I was thinking to have the threads update (by increasing) a value in `redux` called `MessageThreadUpdateCount` which would be a number. That would be done each time any UI connected value changes. The `FlatList` then uses that  `redux` value as its `ExtraData` prop. Hence updating when that changes. Using a boolean instead of a number would be raise the question: what should set it to false, and when? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Rather than us imagining your code you should add [mcve] to your question so it can be debug by people. Updating data property of `FlatList` should fire a re-render.

Comment: @bennygenel actually no unfortunately. The FlatList need the extraData prop to trigger the re-render.

Comment: @bennygenel I do not have a bug / code that is not working. This is more of a code engineering question. The issue is already known where updating an array's contents doesn't trigger UI update. And I know I have to use ExtraData, but more on how so, given the described setup..,.

Comment: There is couple of approaches to go with. You can use extraData like you said, you can map your props to state and use data from state or you can use shouldComponentUpdate to decide a re-render. This is much more depends on the project and the developer preference.

Comment: @bennygenel makes sense. Was wondering if there was a standard approach. Seems like its circumstantial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the list to update you need to set the 'extraData' prop of the FlatList component,

> This is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if props remain shallow- equal. Make sure that everything your renderItem function depends on is passed as a prop (e.g. extraData) that is not === after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the data prop and parent component state.

exemple

```
 <FlatList
    data={this.props.data}
    extraData={this.state}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
  />
```

*With your state being change when you receive a new message. Note that you can replace 'this.state' by any variable updated when you get a new Message could be a counter for example.*

(source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Hope this will help you.